# Apache rewrite rule to add a slash between .com and path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need a rule that will take

```
http://example.comfile.php
```

and change it to

```
http://example.com/file.php
```

Comment: An URL of `http://mydomain.comfile.php` is not going to end up at your web server at all.

Comment: Good point. The request is being made via ajax ... and 'someone' is responding with a 500. Hadn't considered it wasn't us.

Comment: Controlling the message. Sounds like a Facebook/Twitter job.

Comment: @JAyenGreen, your right, I decided to give the answer. :-)

Comment: @PatS That you were responsive in a positive way actually makes my day, really. It might sound facetious, but it isn’t, I’m being honest… gives me a smile that there is still sanity to be had in the world 

Answer (score 0):

There is no rewrite rule that will solve your problem.  The problem must be fixed on the client side that is creating the URL.
For example, if you have php code that generates the url

`httpexamplecomindexhtml`

There is no rewrite rule that can rewrite it to

`http://example.com/index.html`

The fix must be performed on the client side to generate the properly formatted URL.